# Breaking CCs in letter class across pages

Tags: page-breaking, letters

It seems in the letter class that CCs don't get split across page breaks.
Is there some way to make this happen?

I'm including addresses in the CC, so it can become quite long.
and if it doesn't break across pages, it wastes a lot of space.

Alternatives/workarounds also appreciated.

Example follows. The output occupies two pages, with a big gap left on the first page. Commenting out the last two (of four CCs) makes the letter fit on one page.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\signature{(Someone)}
\address{Street \\ City \\ Country}
\newcommand\drd[1]{#1,\\
The Little House in the Big Garden,\\
Oxenthorpe Road,\\
Puddleby on the Marsh,\\
Slopshire\\
England,\\
UK}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{\drd{Dr. John Dolittle}}
\opening{Dear Dr. Dolittle,}
\dots
\closing{Sincerely,}
\cc{\drd{Jip}}
\cc{\drd{Gub-Gub}}
\cc{\drd{Dab-Dab}}
\cc{\drd{Polynesia}}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

NOTE: Thanks to @egreg for the solution. This workaround is not necessary for `scrlttr2`, which handles breaks in CCs just fine.

Comment: `\cc` includes its argument in a `\parbox`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have several `\cc` commands and you want to allow breaks between them, you have to override the `\stopbreaks` declaration that's issued by `\closing`, which disables page breaks.

Since `\par` comes to mean “end paragraph and issue `\nobreak`”, adding `\penalty0` after `\par` is a good remedy.

```
\documentclass{letter}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cc}[1]{%
  \par\noindent
  \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
    \@hangfrom{\normalfont\ccname: }%
    \ignorespaces #1\strut}\par\penalty\z@
}
\makeatother


\signature{(Someone)}
\address{Street \\ City \\ Country}
\newcommand\drd[1]{#1,\\
The Little House in the Big Garden,\\
Oxenthorpe Road,\\
Puddleby on the Marsh,\\
Slopshire\\
England,\\
UK}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{\drd{Dr. John Dolittle}}
\opening{Dear Dr. Dolittle,}
\dots
\closing{Sincerely,}
\cc{\drd{Jip}}
\cc{\drd{Gub-Gub}}
\cc{\drd{Dab-Dab}}
\cc{\drd{Polynesia}}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

#### Explanation

The `\closing` command is defined by

```
\newcommand{\closing}[1]{\par\nobreak\vspace{\parskip}%
  \stopbreaks
  <...irrelevant code omitted...>
  \par}
```

where `\stopbreaks` is

```
\newcommand*{\stopbreaks}{%
  \interlinepenalty\@M
  \def\par{\@@par\nobreak}%
  \let\\\@nobreakcr
  \let\vspace\@nobreakvspace}
```

which basically means “don't break across pages from this point on”. The definition of `\cc` is similar to the redefinition above, with just the `\penalty\z@` missing, so `\par` does `\@@par\nobreak` (where `\@@par` is the primitive `\par`) and no page break are allowed. The command `\nobreak` is a shorthand for `\penalty10000`.

However, TeX is allowed to break at any penalty in vertical mode, provided the value is less than 10000. So, if we add a “neutral” penalty like `\penalty0` after `\nobreak`, we are allowing a page break.

What's the difference between `\penalty0` and `\penalty\z@`? Almost none, if we're in a context where `\makeatletter` is in force. The code could have `\penalty0` (but ***no*** `%` to mask the end of line); using `\z@` avoids any doubt about protecting the line ending or not.

Comment: To be clear, I'm Ok with individual CCs not breaking, I have a group of CCs, and they appear to not be breaking as a group. I'll give an example.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Here you find the solution.